# T-SQL: Deciding between 2 WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. The main query's `WHERE` clause could be either

```
WHERE (MyTable.Code = 'A')
```

or

```
WHERE (MyTable.Code <> 'A')
```

**QUESTION**: What's the easiest way to handle this? Have an input parameter that tells which condition to use then use an if statement which uses the first SQL statement, else the second? Doesn't seem like the most efficient way.

Also, is there a way to pass the entire `WHERE` clause in as an input parameter?

Example parameter

```
@WHERE: "WHERE (MyTable.Code='A')
```

so that you can do...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE @WHERE
```

Comment: Dynamic sql, equal or nor equal as parameter.

Comment: It sounds like you might be going down the route to where the article [dynamic search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) would be the best thing to read.

Answer (score 3):

Most simple route would be to have additional parameter that will decide which one to use in the following manner. The only problem is when you start to do this you can end up with bad execution plan.

```
DECLARE @Bit BIT = 0;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable AS m
WHERE (m.Code <> 'A' AND @Bit = 0)
    OR (m.Code = 'A' AND @Bit = 1)
```

In order to avoid bad execution plans you have several different option.

- OPTION (RECOMPILE)
- OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE=VALUE))
- OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE UNKNOWN))
- Use local variables

You can read more about it at [Parameter Sniffing Problem and Possible Workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx)

In your case the easiest would be use of local variables.

For example:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetSomeData (@pBit BIT)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Bit BIT = @pBit;

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.MyTable AS m
    WHERE (m.Code <> 'A' AND @Bit = 0)
        OR (m.Code = 'A' AND @Bit = 1)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Having an if statement in the stored procedure to decide between the two queries is better (in my opinion) than passing the where clause in as a parameter.  If you pass the where clause in as a parameter then the logic of your database is leaking up into the layer above.  Also depending on how you build your layer above you can open yourself up to a sql injection attack.

It would appear though that they are two different queries so maybe this would be better suited as two stored procedures and then decide in your calling code which one to call.

Comment: Actually, it isn't. SQL Server will cache the execution plan of the stored procedure the first time it runs, which will result in a plan that's suitable only for one of the two options

Comment: Will the execution plan not be the same?  it is just doing a different query on the same column?

Comment: +1 to this answer. @PanagiotisKanav the two queries will have a different where clauses, different queryplans and the bit parameter is not part of the queries. That means that each query is optimized for its job and the value of the parameter does not influence the queryplans created. All other (so far) answers that builds a combined where clause will end up just as you suggested. SQL Server will build a where clause that best matches the value of the bit column and that can be really bad in the other case. Dynamic SQL would work or a query hint `option recompile` on the combined where clause.

Comment: @KevinHolditch No, the queryplan for the two queries will be different because the where clause is different and that is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something quick and easy that works you can use the flag (or whatever condition determines which WHERE clause to use) and combine both into a single WHERE clause.

`WHERE (@flag = 1 AND code = 'A') OR (@flag = 0 AND code <> 'A')`

For more advanced SQL on the fly, you can use [dynamic sql](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use dynamic SQL, but in this case it's not necessary.  Just use a conditional WHERE clause:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
(@IsA bit)
AS

SELECT  ...
WHERE (@IsA = 1 AND MyTable.Code='A')
   OR (@IsA = 0 AND MyTable.Code<>'A')
```

> is there a way to pass the entire WHERE clause in as an input parameter?

Well, sure, you could pass it in as a string, but there are lots of risks with doing that:

1. The procedure can;t be pre-compiled because your SQL will be dynamic.
2. You increase the risk of SQL injection attacks
3. The client must intimately know the structure of the underlying SQL in order to provide a proper WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

If your input parameter is a boolean, or anything for that matter, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (MyTable.Code='A' AND MyParameter='Equals')
   OR  (My.Table.Code <> 'A' AND MyParementer='NotEqual')
```

I've used something similar to this in the past to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a parameter to dictate which WHERE clause will be used.

Assuming that you have a parameter called @WhereClauseToUse.

You could have something like this:

```
select *
from table
where (@WhereClauseToUse = 1 and Code = 'A')
    or (@WhereClauseToUse = 2 and Code <> 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used conditions in the WHERE clause, something like

```
-- @A = 1/true, then WHERE (MyTable.Code = 'A')
-- @A = 0/false, then WHERE (MyTable.Code <> 'A')
declare @A bit

WHERE ((MyTable.Code = 'A' and @A = 1) OR (MyTable.Code <> 'A' and @A = 0))
```